# Where can I use where?

Tags: haskell

Well, i had to do this function that, given a list and a number, it returns the element of the list in the position of number (being first position 0)

basically its the function `(!!)`. The problem that I face is that I need to restrict to this function , case the position given is bigger than the positions in the list, i tried to use a        when but it doesn't work, it shows this error:

```
parse error on input `where'
```

Can I use a `where` here? in which situations can i use a `where`?

```
localiza:: [a]->Int->a

localiza [a] 0 = a
localiza (a:as) b  = localiza (as) (b-1) 
                     where b+1 <= length(a)
```

Comment: if the `position` is less than the length of the list, it returns the element at the position, but what the function should return if the position is bigger than the length?

Comment: What you here want is a guard, not a `where`.

Comment: how can i use the guard? if the position is bigger than the lenght it should not be possible

Comment: I would recommend 1) to avoid using `a` for both the name of a _type_, and an element of your list, and 2) to avoid using `[a]` in `localiza [a] 0 =...` unless you really mean that such equation only applies to lists of length one. In types, `[a]` is the type of a list with zero or more elements. In values, and patterns, `[a]` is a list whose length is exactly one. You likely want something like `localiza (x:rest) 0 = x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell `where` introduces a set of local definitions. It can be attached to any definition to define variables that are local to that definition. So the problem in your code is not where you use `where`, it's what you use it for.

You're not trying to define local variables, you're trying to add a condition to your pattern. For that you use pattern guards, which have the syntax `pattern | boolean-condition`, i.e. `localiza (a:as) b | b < length as = ...`.

That said, this isn't really a good way to do this. `length` is an O(n) operation, so checking the length at each step of the iteration wastes a lot of time. Instead you could just catch the case when the list becomes empty, which will only happen if the index was out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give this example from the Haskell wiki.

```
elementAt' (x:_) 1  = x
elementAt' [] _     = error "Index out of bounds"
elementAt' (_:xs) k
  | k < 1           = error "Index out of bounds"
  | otherwise       = elementAt' xs (k - 1)
```

This does not check the length so often, only exiting when the list becomes empty.